# TensorFlow install on Ubuntu error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I try to install the TensorFlow in Ubuntu, following the [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)
I don't have GPU in my VM so i tried with CPU version of TensorFlow in Python3 
Create a Virtualenv environment by issuing one of the following command getting error. please help

1. `sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev python-virtualenv`
2. `virtualenv --system-site-packages -p /home/ubuntu/workspace/tensor/`

[image]

Comment: should you not ask this question here:-https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

the python code throws os error: permission denied
i suggest you could try strace,
it would give the details of what cause permission denied